# echoing two things in different if statements

Tags: php, if-statement

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    $serv_id = $_POST['serv_id'];
    $time    = $_POST["time"];
    $date    = $_POST["date"];

    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
    {
        echo "sorry you're not logged in.";
        exit();
    }

    if(date('w', strtotime($date)) == 6 || date('w', strtotime($date)) == 0) 
    {
        echo 'Event is on a weekend and cannot be booked.'; 
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo 'Thank for you booking with Claires hair and beauty';
        $time = $time. ":00:00";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT time FROM tbl_booking WHERE time = '$time' AND date = '$date'") or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $result - Error: ".mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) 
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_booking (tbl_mem_id, serv_id, date, time) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['id']}','$serv_id','$date','$time')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        location: 'dashboard.php';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo("this time is already booked");
    }
}
```

Essentially I'm trying to make it check if they're logged in by checking a session variable, then check if the date they have entered is a weekend and then if the date/time being entered is already taken as if it is it just needs to echo `this time is already booked`.

But what is happening is when the slot is already taken? It echos

```
Thank for you booking with Claires hair and beautythis time is already booked
```

Comment: location: 'dashboard.php'; what is this for ?????

Comment: You have an additional curly bracket at the end after mysqli_error which belongs to the date check and seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Code:

```
if(date('w', strtotime($date)) == 6 || date('w', strtotime($date)) == 0) 
    {
        echo 'Event is on a weekend and cannot be booked.'; 
    } 
    else 
    {

        $time = $time. ":00:00";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT time FROM tbl_booking WHERE time = '$time' AND date = '$date'") or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $result - Error: ".mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) 
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_booking (tbl_mem_id, serv_id, date, time) VALUES ('{$_SESSION['id']}','$serv_id','$date','$time')";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        echo 'Thank for you booking with Claires hair and beauty';//this is right place
        location: 'dashboard.php';// Don't know what you trying to do here
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo("this time is already booked");
    }
```

If you want to redirect to another page in php use this:

```
header('Location: yourpage.php');
```

[PHP Header Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Be aware that your code is open to [sql injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Use something like [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to prevent that.